# Should my DAOs (Database Entities) Directly match my UI Objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I am trying to figure out best practice for N-Tier application design.  When designing the objects my UI needs and those that will be persisted in the DB some of my colleagues are suggesting that the objects be one in the same.  This doesn't not feel right to me and I am ultimately looking for some best practice documentation to help me in this decision.

**EDIT:**
Let me clarify this by saying that the tables (Entity Classes) that are in the DB are identical to the objects used in the UI

I honestly do not understand why I would want to design this way given that other applications may want to interact with my Data Access Layer....or it is just ignorance or lack of understanding on my part.

Any documentation, information you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Just want to better understand these concepts and I am having a hard time finding some good information on the best practice for implementing these patterns (Or it is right in front of me on what I found and I didn't understand what was being outlined).

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, DAOs and database entities are two very different things.

Now to the question. You're right. The database entities are mapped to a database schema, and this database schema should follow the database design best practices, and be normalized. The UI sometimes dislays exactly the information from a given entity, but often show data that comes from multiple entities, in an aggregate format. Or, to the contrary, they only show a small part of a given entity.

For example, it would make sense for a UI to show a product name, description and price along with the name of its category, along with the number of remaining items in stock, along with the manufacturer of the product. It would make no sense to have a persistent entity containing all those fields.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet I didn't word question appropriately.  I realize that the DAOs and DB entiteis are different.  Thanks for the response makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

In general and according to most "best practices" comments, yes, those two layers should be decoupled and there should be separate objects.

BUT: if your mapping would only be a one-to-one-mapping without any further functionality in the non-database-object, why introduce an additional object? So, it depends. (as usual ;-) ).

Don't use additional objects if the introduced overhead is bigger than the gain. And don't couple the two layers if re-usability is a first-class-goal. That may not be the case with some legacy applications, e.g.